# How to automate O-Auth2 web browser opening to get access token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, oauth-2.0, puppeteer

So I am working with google sheets API , where I need to authorize the credentials before I can hit api for my account , for that OAuth2 client provides an auth URL which opens in browser and there I have to login in Gmail account and then accept the permissions and then it redirects to a redirect URI and in it's URL there is a code.

But I want to get all this done automatically as this will be part of my backend code , and I want it be automated without me going to browser and logging in . Can this be done using puppeteer ? or anything else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option to avoid user interaction is to use a service account with [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account). And to use this, you need to be a Workspace domain admin, and you can only act on behalf of users in your Workspace domain.

If you are not a domain admin, there's no way to avoid the workflow you mentioned, with user interaction.

#### Reference:

- [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)

Comment: @lamblichus With service account way can I hit this API
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${spreadsheetId}/export?format=${format}&id=${spreadsheetId} 

without having to send access token in headers , as I would have to do in oAuth2 way2 ?

Comment: @ShubhamSeth You would send an access token, but the access token is retrieved programmatically, without user interaction. I don't know which language you're using, but here's a description of the process https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

Comment: @lamblichus I have created the service account with domain-wide delegation , but I am unable to understand how to get access token from that service account. And language I am using is Javascript (NodeJS)

Comment: @ShubhamSeth The library can do that for you and call the API in one step. See, for example, the sample in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60092848) (in this case it's calling Directory API instead of Sheets API, but the workflow is the same). Or alternatively, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58565907) which uses Sheets API but no impersonation. I hope this is useful to you.